# Find the possible values of $\dim( U \cap W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Here's the problem:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $U,W \subseteq V$. Assume $\dim(V)=7 ,\dim (U) = 4 $ and $\dim(W)= 5$. Find the possible values of $\dim( U \cap W)$.

I get $\dim(U \cap W) \in \{2,3,4\}$, by the dimension formula. Is this correct?

Comment: From the tag description for [tag:dimension-theory-algebra]: For questions about notions of dimension, rank, or length used in abstract algebra (e.g. Krull dimension, homological dimensions, composition length, Goldie dimension). Questions about dimension of vector spaces, and rank of linear transformations are better placed under the [linear-algebra] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly what you mean by the "dimension formula". That being said, we have
$$
\dim(U) + \dim(W) = \dim(U \cap W) + \dim(U + W).
$$
The left hand side must be $9$.  Since $\dim(U + W) \in \{5,6,7\}$, we can conclude that $\dim(U \cap W) = 9 - \dim(U + W) \in \{2,3,4\}$.

Comment: I used the formula you stated. Surely $\dim(U) +\dim(W) =4 +5 = 9 $?

Comment: @user736948 well that's a silly mistake.  Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!